# 複数ファイルをffmpegで一括変換したい

Tags: ffmpeg

拡張子wavやm4aの複数ファイルからmp4に一括変換したいです。

Answer (score 0):

```
for f in *.wmv ; do ffmpeg -i $f $f.mp4; done
```

ワンライナーでこのように書けると思います。

Comment: これだとファイル名にスペースが入った時に問題が起こる気がします．あと [`${f%wav}`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) とか使うと `*.wmv.mp4` にならなくてすみますね．